# Apple In App Purchase & Apple "Store Credit"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We recently had a purchase on one of our apps. However, to our knowledge or the apps knowledge, the purchase never came through.

This only came to our attention when our user alerted us that they never received their virtual good. After looking into this, we saw the app sent the call off to itunes to process the payment, but never received the call back.

We asked the user to forward on the receipt to confirm the payment. The iTunes receipt read:

> In App Purchase   $15.99
>
> Store Credit Total:   $0.13
>
> Payment Card Total:   $15.86
>
> Order Total:          $15.99

"Store Credit"?! Would this have had some effect on the call back process to our app? Meaning we missed this sale totally? Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if the 'Store credit' have any effect but we are experiencing a similar situation:

Sometimes our customers complain that they have purchased an IAP item and never received the credit in the app.

When we check their log (we keep a special log for that) we see that we got SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed response with 'Cannot connect to iTunes store' and later on, after 1-3 minutes we get SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased.

We tried to ask Apple about it but couldn't get any explanation. I hope more people are having the same problem and can help us understand the situation.